# Trying to recover my TTL-Wifi

Tags: esp8266

So I bought What I tought was a DOIT Wifi-TTL and after a few bad manipulations I wiped the firmware...
That means the leds are not turning on anymore and I see no activity on it when I connect to it with a USB-TTL...

The FCC ID on it says 2al3b-esp-m that seams to indicate a ESP-8285
(https://fccid.io/2AL3B-ESP-M/User-Manual/User-Manual-3413969)

I tried to flash it with Arduino ESP8285 samples and it flash right but I can't figure how / where I could retrieve the functionality that I had in the pas (login the the web server of it and interact with the TTL...

```
esptool.py v2.8
Serial port COM6
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8285
Features: WiFi, Embedded Flash
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: 84:0d:8e:41:22:82
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 1MB
Compressed 280400 bytes to 205882...
Wrote 280400 bytes (205882 compressed) at 0x00000000 in 18.3 seconds (effective 122.7 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.

Leaving...
```

Comment: https://github.com/SmartArduino/SZDOITWiKi/wiki/Drivers%2CFirmwares%2C-and-Tools